# How to enable x-axis and y-axis line in GGPLOT theme_classic()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

With this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, color=dose, shape=dose)) + 
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))+
  labs(title="Plot of length  by dose",x="Dose (mg)", y = "Length")
p + theme_classic()
```

I expect to get image like this:

[image]

But how come I get this instead:

[image]

Notice the missing x-axis an y-axis line.
How can I enable it?

This is `theme_classic()` specific issue.

Comment: OK, same for me: `R version 3.3.0` and `ggplot2_2.1.0`

Comment: If you look at the definition of theme_classic you'll see that both axis.line.x and axis.line.y are set to element_blank. Either change this definition yourself or you could use theme_classic2 in the package survminer.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution from this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1565)

```
p + theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid'),
          axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid'))
```

**Edit**

If you are running into this issue, updating `ggplot2` should fix the issue, and the solution above shouldn't be necessary.

**Edit** 2023-06-29

As of `ggplot2 3.4.0`, the `size` argument of `element_line()` is deprecated and `linewidth` should be used instead. However, as mentioned above, the latest version of `ggplot2` should not have this issue, and the `theme` addition should no longer be needed.

```
p + theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'black', linewidth = 5, linetype='solid'),
          axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black', linewidth = 5, linetype='solid'))
```

[image]